# Trouble with ruby Development Kit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have been having trouble with the DevKit that I got from rubyinstaller.org/downloads. I am following the instructions from https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit . When I go to test my installation by running `gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby` I get the following:

```
    C:\DevKit>gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rdiscount:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        "C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
checking for random()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby
        --with-rdiscount-dir
        --without-rdiscount-dir
        --with-rdiscount-include
        --without-rdiscount-include=${rdiscount-dir}/include
        --with-rdiscount-lib
        --without-rdiscount-lib=${rdiscount-dir}/lib
C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier
 failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:435:in `try_link
0'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:440:in `try_link
'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_func
'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:797:in `block in
 have_func'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in
 checking_for'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2
 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in
 postpone'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone
'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking
_for'
        from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:796:in `have_fun
c'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/rdiscount-2.0.7 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount
-2.0.7/ext/gem_make.out
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the dev kit in a directory with spaces is a source of trouble.

Don't use `C:/Program Files` but another directory, e.g. `C:/ProgramFiles` or `C:/bin` ...

See also

- [Issues installing Ruby and Rails and DevKit on windows 7 x64 - fix needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559912/issues-installing-ruby-and-rails-and-devkit-on-windows-7-x64-fix-needed)
- [Bundle command not found. Bad Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575644/bundle-command-not-found-bad-interpreter/10575692#10575692)

Comment: Ya moving my ruby-1.9.3 folder into another directory without spaces helped. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this here since there is not enough space in the comment.

I ran into issues like this in the past. I was able to get by them, but what I quickly found was that the server that I was running the RoR application on was linux based. I found that the development environment in Windows worked fine, but ran into a bunch of problems when pushing it to production. To fix the problem, I had installed the DevKit in a path that couldn't be determined. I ended up installing everything under C:\railskit

Since then and for the past several years, I've used these tools to develop RoR applications

- VirtualBox - Virtualized Development Environment
- Ubuntu - Development OS
- KiTTY - Windows based SSH Tool (based on PuTTY)
- SublimeText2 - Windows Version

I installed Ruby on Rails in a development environment and used Samba to share the development folder. I SSH into the box with KiTTY and use that to generate the different controllers and to run the webrick service. I do all of the coding within SublimeText2 within Windows.