# Trying to install Jekyll on Windows 8 (x64): Error installing fast-stemmer-1.0.2.gem

Tags: ruby, windows-8, rubygems, jekyll

I'm trying to get Jekyll running on Windows 8 x64, using this manual:

[Running Jekyll on Windows](http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2011/09/01/runningjekyllwindows.html)

I'm using the following two downloads from [rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/):

- Ruby 2.0.0-p0 (x64)
- DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe

So I set up both Ruby and the DevKit according to the manual (expect it's newer versions). I tried running a little Hello World .rb script and it's working fine, path variables are set.

I then try to run *gem install jekyll* and I get the following output:

[*gem install jekyll* - output on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/JqtHffax)

The problem seems to be with the gem called *fast-stemmer-1.0.2.gem*, or so it seems.

Unfortunately I have practically zero experience with Ruby or Jekyll and have no idea what is going on here. Could someone please take a look at the output and send me into the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried uninstall Ruby/DevKit and try the whole thing again, but this time, install Ruby to the default directory like `C:\Ruby200-x64` instead of `C:/Program Files/Ruby/Ruby200-x64`

As I suspect the space in your ruby directory could be the issue. (Line 296 of your error txt)

> /usr/bin/install: target
>   `Files/Ruby/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/lib'
>   is not a directory make: *** [install-so] Error 1

Also quote from [Issues installing Ruby and Rails and DevKit on windows 7 x64 - fix needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559912/issues-installing-ruby-and-rails-and-devkit-on-windows-7-x64-fix-needed)

> Seems you installed Ruby (along the DevKit?) inside a directory with
>   spaces.
>
> As indicated during Ruby own installer, path with spaces are not
>   recommended (that is why default is C:\Ruby193
>
> GCC, the compiler that is part of DevKit, has problems with path with
>   spaces, so installation of DevKit is also recommended to be placed in
>   a path without spaces (e.g. C:\DevKit)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! It's now running although installing gems and plugins is difficult. I think I will be setting up an Ubuntu VM for this after all.